# Nested ui-view animations

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I'm struggling to create separate animations on two ui-view elements simultaneously (or any animations), using ui router.

My basic site layout is:

- main.html (has one ui-view, which is faded in)

  - customerMain.html which sits in "main"

**main.html**

```
<div id="work-container">
    <div class="menu">

        <!-- some ul/li stuff -->

    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div ui-view class="view-animate-main-container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**customerMain.html**

```
<div id="customer-work-container">
    <div class='menu'>
        <div ui-view='menu' class='view-animate-main-container'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div ui-view='content' class="view-animate-sub-container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CustomerModule**

```
angular.module('btApp.crm.customers', ['ui.router'])
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider

    .state('main.customerMain', {
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: '/ng/crm/customers/templates/customerMain.html',
    })

    .state('main.customerMain.overview', {
        url: '/customer/:id',
        views: {
            'menu@main.customerMain': {
                templateUrl: "/ng/crm/customers/templates/menu.html",
                controller: 'CRMCustomerMenuCtrl'
            },
                'content@main.customerMain': {
                templateUrl: "/ng/crm/customers/templates/overview.html",
                controller: 'CRMCustomerOverviewCtrl'
            },
        }
    })
}]);
```

In a nutshell, i'm trying to perform different animations on the two content views, but everything i've tried doesn't seem to take effect, even if i remove all the parent animations there is still no animations being applied to the views. I'm not entirely sure if ng-enter is being added, it's too quick to see.

What i originally thought was happening was the fade-in animation was being applied to the main ui-view, which in then turn also runs while loading the child ui-views thus you don't see the animations, however, removing parent animations and delaying child animations, still nothing.

Would welcome any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

To my experience ngAnimate doesn't work with ui-router's child views after the parent view has been changed at least once (it works on initial page load though, when the parent view and its children views are loaded by the router initial match. What is more weird transition works from the second try, while it completely skips the transition that should be there on first attempt to switch child's view). My guess of why is that would be that ngAnimate cant track new nodes inside the parent ui-view that are also containers for children ui-views, but as I said: it is just a guess.

And to help observe what is happening in the DOM (whether ng-enter, ng-leave, etc... classes are applied or not) you can just temporarily set your CSS transition time to a long value, e.g. 100 seconds

Answer (score 0):

**ngAnimateChildren** directive might be relevant to you, given that you have nested ui-view elements involving structural animations. See [ngAnimateChildren docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/directive/ngAnimateChildren)

> ngAnimateChildren allows you to specify that children of this element should animate even if any of the children's parents are currently animating. By default, when an element has an active enter, leave, or move (structural) animation, child elements that also have an active structural animation are not animated.

Also make sure that you are using the correct css selectors ie `.view-animate-main-container.ng-enter` & `view-animate-sub-container.ng-enter` & that they have a *transition* specified.